# How can I use glTranslatef in openGL C++

Tags: c++, opengl

I tried to make a simple program that user can move the polygon by mouse drag. but it won't work at all at "translatef"..
How can fix this problem?
My source code is here.

```
void dragMouse(GLint x, GLint y) {

    x = setX(x);
    y = setY(y);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

    if (mouseMode == 2) {   
        printf("드래그로 도형을 옮깁니다.\n");
        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef((mouseX - x), (mouse - y), 0.0);
        glutPostRedisplay();
        glPopMatrix();
    }
    else if (mouseMode == 3) {
        angle += -(x - mouseX)*10.0 / 3.14;
        glRotatef(angle, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
    else if (mouseMode == 4) {
        scale *= (1.0 + (y - mouseY) / 100.0);
        glScalef(scale, scale, 0.0);
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
glTranslatef((mouseX - x), (mouse - y), 0.0);
glutPostRedisplay();
glPopMatrix();
```

`glutPostRedisplay` flags GLUT's main loop to call the display function again *as soon as possible*. Which means that the display function will not be called now but later when the main loop so decides (e.g call the display function this frame once event handling is over).

So as you call `glutPostRedisplay` between pushing and popping your matrix, nothing will have changed when the display function is actually called. Moreover, it serves you no purpose to call `glutPostRedisplay` twice in the same function. As I said it only **flags** the main loop to run the display function for this frame, so flagging twice will have no effect.

I advise you to keep model matrix transforms in the display function (or related functions) as much as possible. Spreading `glTranslatef` or `glScalef` into the event handling functions makes it more difficult to maintain or understand what's going on with your scene. Besides, keeping the transforms in the same place makes it easier for you to make changes and add new objects to your scene, which otherwise would be impossible to manage.

Instead, you should store all the data you need to apply those translations, and place them in the display function. Say, you need to translate an object to the screen position of the mouse? Store those coordinates:

```
// Declared somewhere accessible
float objectX, objectY;
...
// Mouse handling function
objectX = (mouse - x);
objectY = (mouse - y);
...
// Display (or related) function
glTranslatef( objectX, objectY, 0.0f );
drawObject();
```

Note I only mentioned doing this to the model matrix. It is very common to setup the projection matrix very few times (only when the window is resized) and that's fine. Unless you have a very specific modelview transform that would be applied to all objects (and even then) you should follow my advice.

Note that you're not using the matrix modes properly. You're applying transforms to the projection matrix when you should be applying them to the modelview matrix. You should really read up on how matrices work. Search for **projection**, **view** and **model** matrices, **transforms** and **viewing volumes**.
Also it's probably more useful to learn modern OpenGL instead of the deprecated functionality.